# Angular2 Routing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I was following [this](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/16/routing-in-angular-2.html) tutorial of routing in Angular, and it just doesn't work. When I use the 'comp' selector to put it's HTML code, it works, but when I'm trying to route it with router-outlet, it just shows the header from `index.html`.

I have the following:

main.ts:

```js
import * as ng from 'angular2/angular2';
import {Comp} from './comp';
@ng.Component({
    selector: 'my-app'
})
@ng.View({
    directives: [ng.formDirectives, ng.RouterOutlet],
    template: `
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Start</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </main>
  `
})
@ng.RouteConfig([{ path: '/', component: Comp }])
class AppComponent {
}
ng.bootstrap(AppComponent, [ng.routerInjectables]);
```

comp.ts:

```js
import * as ng2 from 'angular2/angular2';
@ng2.Component({
    selector: 'comp'
})
@ng2.View({
    template: `
    <h1>hi<h1>
  `
})
export class Comp {
    constructor() {
    }
}
```

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test3</title>
    <script src="lib/traceur/traceur.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/system.js/dist/system.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular2-build/angular2.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular2-build/router.dev.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.config({
            packages: { 
                'js': {
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                } 
            }
        });
        System.import('/js/main');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello There</h1>
    <my-app></my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have commented the `router.dev.js` file D: !

Comment: You're right but that's not it. I mistakenly posted an older version

Comment: See this [example](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/examples/src/routing/inbox-app.ts) and see the imports. Which version are you using?

Comment: I have a working sample here: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/routing-in-angular-2.0
There is also a live demo of the code here:http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-2.0-examples

Answer (score 7):

**Breaking changes were introduced in `angular@2.0.0-alpha.41`**

- `routerInjectables` was renamed to `ROUTER_BINDINGS`
- `ROUTER_BINDINGS` was then renamed to `ROUTER_PROVIDERS`

*Aside: Lots of breaking changes lately so virtually none of the online examples are reliable.*

**Use `ROUTER_PROVIDERS`**

*It includes:*

- `RouteRegistry` - the registry of defined routes
- `LocationStrategy = PathLocationStragety` - match routes by path

This is basically a shortcut to bootstrap your Router with a default setup.

**For example:**

```
@Component ({
...
})
@View ({
...
})
@RouteConfig ({
...
})
class App {}

bootstrap(App, [ ROUTER_PROVIDERS ]);
```

*Sources:*

- [angular/CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-alpha41-2015-10-13)
- [angular/pr#4654](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/4654)

Answer (score 4):

You can find current most popular working example of routing [here](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed)

Look into *app/app.ts*:

```
import {Component, bind, bootstrap, ViewEncapsulation} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {
  RouteConfig,
  ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
  ROUTER_BINDINGS,
  ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT
} from 'angular2/router';

import {Home} from './components/home/home';
import {About} from './components/about/about';
...
@Component({ /// your root component
})
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/', component: Home, as: 'Home' },
  { path: '/about', component: About, as: 'About' }
])
class App {}

bootstrap(App, [
  ROUTER_BINDINGS,
  bind(ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT).toValue(App)
]);
```

Comment: FYI, the `Route.as` parameter was changed to `Route.name`.https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/7d83959be56780b1ba9cf7efb6cd96452bec2761. Otherwise, good example +1.

Answer (score 2):

On the tutorial you are following they finally stated it's deprecated, you can read it in bold:

```
Deprecation Note

We are very sorry, but this article is out of date and has been deprecated. Usually, we keep our articles up to date, however, with this one it's very likely that we've written a complete new version.
```

If you wish to use the routing component I would suggest to update your Angular 2 version. Be aware that quite a few settings has changed in RC, so you'll probably will need to set up the config again from the official site and make few changes.

Another user had similar issue like you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37262826/routing-angular2-nothing-appears) and with upgrading the problem was solved. Just upgrade the version, fix the config and use this official documentation from [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)

Answer (score 1):

May be too late for answer but wroth reading whole answer, give it a try :P

- `View` is no more in angular2, if you are using still `@view` annotation it may cause producing some kind of error. so Only Component is the place that will hold the all options.

As per officials , @View metadata decorator has been deprecated in beta.10 release.

- `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` need when you are doing stuff related to Routing in angular2. by injecting `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` in the list of directives, `routerLink` and `router-outlet` property required for routing automatically available to your component. you can inject `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` at the time  of bootstrapping your app instead of injecting every time in every component's directives list.

Instead of posting whole answer posting link to some usefull answers related to routing see here also -

- [Angular 2 router examples + @RouteConfig typing support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36823186/5043867)
- [Router Providers for angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33196880/5043867)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the / in your path as below :
@ng.RouteConfig([{ path: "", component: Comp }]).

You don't need to specify the slash in your route configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Since you don't provide the error message, here's a working sample https://github.com/ajtowf/ng2_play with a video tutorial https://youtu.be/ZsGRiHSaOxM

Answer (score -1):

The angular2 router has evolved phenomenally, for all those still stuck with the old tutorials that have not reflected the changes be ready for massive surprises. I would suggest you guys to have a look at my inventman project, which is on the bleeding edge of angular2. I am not promoting it, as it is a closed-source project. You can have ideas about routing and almost all angular2 principles from it. Unlike other tutorials it is a full blown working project.

https://github.com/debanjanbasu/inventman