# Getting Angular2 error 'No provider for Router! (RouterOutlet -> Router)'

Tags: angular-routing, angular

I use **Angular2 alpha39 and Babel** to transpile the ES6 JS file. I'm not using typescript.

I created a component which displays correctly. I added a **router-outlet** to the template. When I run the app, I get the error message:

**No provider for Router! (RouterOutlet -> Router)**

The call stack is:

[image]

Here is the snippet of code:

template:

```
.... // Removed for brevity
<div class="contenttext">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
.... // Removed for brevity
```

Component file:

```
import { Component, View, bootstrap,  OnInit } from 'angular2/angular2';
import { RouteConfig, RouterOutlet, RouterLink } from 'angular2/router';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'winjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard-app'
})
@View({
    templateUrl: '../js/dashboard.html',
    directives: [ ContentComponent, FamiliesComponent, RouterOutlet, RouterLink ]
})
@RouteConfig([ 
    { path: '/employees', component: EmployeesComponent, as: 'employees'} 
]) 
class DashboardAppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() {
    }

    onInit() {
        WinJS.UI.processAll().done(function() {
            var splitView = document.querySelector(".splitView").winControl;
            new WinJS.UI._WinKeyboard(splitView.paneElement);
        })
    }
}

bootstrap(DashboardAppComponent);
```

Comment: Add `ROUTER_BINDINGS` in your bootstrap.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

you have to use:

1. ROUTER_BINDINGS in your bootstrap.
2. in your index.html.
3. if possible use state i.e as "employees" in capitalize i.r as "Employees". (in alpha 42 i have solve one problem this way).

i hope this will surely help you.

### --UPDATE--

after the relese of alpha41:

1. `ROUTER_BINDINGS` has been changed with `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` .
2. Router Aliases should be in the camel case manner.
3. for the Router-outler and router-link you just have to import `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` in your directives property in the component annotation.
4. `Router-link` expects the value to be an array of route names. for more info. refer [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/RouterLink-directive.html) .

for more info regarding Routing you may refer to this tutorial [here](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/routing-in-angular-2.0) .

### ---Update2---

1. Now ( as of alpha-49) router is exported as ng.router.
2. (According to alpha-47 all life cycle hooks renamed as.)

   onActivate, onReuse, onDeactivate, canReuse, canDeactivate

   To :--

   routerOnActivate,routerOnReuse,routerOnDeactivate,routerCanReuse,routerCanDeactivate

### ---Update3---

1. `router-link` is changed to `routerLink`
2. and routeconfig property changed to:

   `{path: '/abc', component: ABC, as: 'abc'}`
   to: 
   `{path: '/xyz' , component: XYZ, name: 'xyz'}`

## --Update 4 --

## UPDATE TO ANGULAR2 RC

There are alot of changes has been made in routing in angular2 after RC some of them points i am going to mention here may help someone :-

1. `angular2/router` has been changed with `@angular/router`
   (also you can use old functionality of routing using import of `@angular/router-deprecated` but as of now we have to use `@angular/router`).
2. `@RouteConfig` has been changed with `@Routes` .

for example :-

```
@Routes([
  {path: '/crisis-center', component: CrisisListComponent},
  {path: '/heroes',        component: HeroListComponent}
])
```

Comment: `ROUTER_BINDINGS` has been deprecated as of alpha41 https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-alpha41-2015-10-13. `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` should be used instead.

Comment: I still gave a +1 because you were right when you originally answered the question. The Angular2 is just still in the 'move fast and break things' stage. I've resigned myself to regularly checking the project issues.

Comment: yes @EvanPlaice i know, but for now angular2 is in beta now so not too many chances for any breaking changes still i keep updating my answer. btw thanx for let me know about updation.

Comment: Stay vigilant. I've been following the development directly via the GitHub repository. The core API may be frozen, but they still have work to do on the Router.

Comment: Yes you are right they still have work to do on the router. yes surely ill update my answer whenever i found any new changes.

Comment: What is the fix for this using version router v3.0.0-alpha8?

Comment: Coding with Angular2 is a right royal pain in the *rse. Every new release seems to break everything before it. How do they think Angular2 can ever catch on when it's near impossible to keep up with the breaking changes ?  Even their tutorials and docs are out of dfate and hardly anything works as described. It has to be the most disjointed and confusing platform on the internet today.

Comment: Hi I'm running into this same problem, however no luck with getting your fixes to work, mind a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42321705/how-to-fix-error-in-app-app-component-html151-caused-by-no-provider-for-rout

Answer (score 9):

**[`2.0.0-alpha.36 (2015-08-31)`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-alpha36-2015-08-31)**

- `routerInjectables` was renamed to `ROUTER_BINDINGS`

**[`2.0.0-alpha.41 (2015-10-13)`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-alpha41-2015-10-13)**

- `ROUTER_BINDINGS` was renamed to `ROUTER_PROVIDERS`

**USE ROUTER_PROVIDERS**

`ROUTER_PROVIDERS` is used to simplify bootstrapping the router.

It includes:

- `RouterRegistry` - the collection of registered routes
- `LocationStrategy = PathLocationStrategy` - match by path

`ROUTER_PROVIDERS` provides 'sane' defaults and should be used unless you need to need a different route `LocationStrategy`.

*Change:*

```
bootstrap(DashboardAppComponent);
```

*To:*

```
bootstrap(DashboardAppComponent, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS
]);
```

*Sources:*

- [angular/commit/ccfadb9](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/ccfadb9b4747d5fd7a3c32f7a8e92b23b07f7fd0)
- [angular/pr#4654](http://angular/pr#4654)

---

**[`2.0.0-alpha.38 (2015-10-03)`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-alpha38-2015-10-03)**

**Route aliases need to be CamelCase (technically PascalCase)**

*Note: this was mentioned already in Pardeep's answer under #3*

If you want to include a link to a route in your template via `router-link` you have to make sure the alias (ie the `name` property) of the route is PascalCase.

If you use plan to use `router-link` modify the route to:

```
{ path: '/employees', component: EmployeesComponent, name: 'Employees'}
```

Then you can add the link in your template with:

```
<a [router-link]="['/Employees']">Employees Link</a>
```

`RouterLink` dynamically inserts a href that matches the route path.

*Note: Reading the issue/pr it appears this change was made to prevent users from confusing the `<route-link>` binding with the route url*

*Sources:*

- https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/IF3_UCJt340/6AgSF76XAwAJ
- [angular/issues#4318](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4318)
- [angular/pr#4643](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/4643)

*Tip:*

If you want to simplify your view directives use `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES`

It includes:

- `RouterLink`
- `RouterOutlet`

---

**Update:**

In the near future, `RouterOutlet`/`<router-outlet>` will be renamed to `RouterViewport`/`<router-viewport>`

*Source:*

- [angular/issues#4679](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4679)

**Update 2:**

- The `RouteConfig` property `as` has been renamed to `name`

*Source:*

- [angular/commit/7d83959](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/7d83959be56780b1ba9cf7efb6cd96452bec2761)

Comment: Here's what I've gathered after bashing my head against my monitor for the past few days. Any time you see a constant (ie all CAPS), the value of that constant is a shortcut to include a group of related classes: these include Components or Directives or Services. The devs appear to be hiding away as much of the messy implementation details as possible to make it easier to get started.

Comment: ROUTER_PROVIDERS was what did it for me.

Answer (score 4):

Answer on **Dec 23rd 2016** (Angular v2.4.1, Router v3.4.1 - should work for any NG v2.x.x + Router v3.x.x)

I just migrated three of our apps from the Webpack Starter Seed to **Angular CLI** (v1.0.0-beta.24) and hit this issue.

Only a tiny fraction of what's on the NG 2 [*massive* router doc page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) is required:

**An app-routing.module.ts file** (typically in src/app/ folder) looking like this sample:

```js
import { NgModule }              from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes }  from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: YourHomePageComponent },
  { path: 'next-page',   component: NextComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**Import AppRoutingModule** into your main module (typically src/app/app.module.ts):

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule  // <--- The import you need to add
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Ensure you have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`** somewhere in your main html (often src/app/app.component.html) as this is where router content is injected.

Comment: The ```RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)``` did the trick for me, thanks :-)

Comment: Just a note, I didn't notice that I had `.forChild` instead of `.forRoot` in my root component, and the error message wound up on this page.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have router defined and declared in AppModule.
Example (look everywhere where routing is mentioned, ignore the rest):

app.routing.ts

```
import { ModuleWithProviders }  from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HeroesComponent }      from './heroes.component';
import {DashboardComponent} from './dashboard.component';
import {HeroDetailComponent} from './hero-detail.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'heroes',
    component: HeroesComponent
  },
  {
  path: 'dashboard',
  component: DashboardComponent
},
{
  path: '',
  redirectTo: '/dashboard',
  pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
  path: 'detail/:id',
  component: HeroDetailComponent
},
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

and app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';

// Imports for loading & configuring the in-memory web api
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';


import { AppComponent }         from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent }   from './dashboard.component';
import { HeroesComponent }      from './heroes.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent }  from './hero-detail.component';
import { HeroService }          from './hero.service';
import { routing }              from './app.routing';
import './rxjs-extensions';
import {HeroSearchComponent} from './hero-search.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,

    routing
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent,
    HeroesComponent,
    HeroSearchComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    HeroService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can save someone an hour:

You get this error if you don't even use routing (for example temporary, maybe you don't import routing config and router-outlet is commented out) BUT you are using Router or ActivatedRoute in some component constructor via dependency injection, like this:

```
@Component({...}})
export class SomeComponent {
constructor(private _router: Router, private _route: ActivatedRoute) {
//may be you are not using _route/_route at the moment at all!
}
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant user Dependency Injection for `Router` if you dont define any routs!
To define route user something similar to following codes:

```
const loginRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: 'foo/bar/baz', component: 'MyRootComponent'}
];

@NgModule({
    imports:      [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        JsonpModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(loginRoutes)
    ],
    providers:    [],
    declarations: [
        MyLoginComponent
    ],
    bootstrap:    [
        MyLoginComponent
    ]
})

export class MyLoginModule
{
}
```