# Optional Parameters While Routing angular2

Tags: routes, angular, routeparams

How to define optional parameters in routing of angular2.my routing configuration like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['../abc',{xyz: blabla}]">
     and 
<a [routerLink]="['../abc']">

{ path: '/abc/:xyz', component: abc, name: 'abc' },  // Here i want xyz as optional perameter
```

so the problem is whenever i am using first method with parameter `blabla` it works fine because at the time of routing i have defined parameter `xyz`
    but in case of second method i dont want to send parameter so the URL becomes

http://localhost:8080/#/sideNav/abc/

which is laoding first time fine but after refresh page nothing shows whole window is getting blank with no contents.
so is there any method to provide optional parameters while routing in angular2.

```
i have also tried without defining parameters like this

{ path: '/abc', component: abc, name: 'abc' }
```

but this will throw error in case of value of xyz is `1` it converts `1` into `true`

Comment: have you tried both together?

Comment: yups but not working.

Comment: why have you used `...` syntax before `/abc`?

Comment: I have tested without `...` syntax and everything works as expected.

Comment: its `..` not `...` this is because i have used child routing not from root as per need

Comment: okay.. i think it should work as without `..` it works. Cant do it practically atm.

Comment: whats the role here `..` in passing parameter ? i don't think child routing creates any problem.

Comment: that I don't know. But I'm having `{path:'/AboutUs', name: 'AboutUs', component: AboutUsCmp}  {path:'/AboutUs/:id', name: 'AboutUs', component: AboutUsCmp}` and  `<a href = "#" [routerLink]="['AboutUs',{id:10}]">About Us</a>`. Now if click this link it give url .../AboutUs/10... if i remove `/10`,refresh it it woks.

Comment: I'm still checking few scenarios with it...

Comment: as your comment try using this `<a href = "#" [routerLink]="['AboutUs']">About Us</a>` and than make some changes and refresh it. actully m using `browserSynch` to reflect changes and beta 0.0 now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define multiple routes with and without parameter having the same component:

```ts
@RouteConfig([{
  path: '/abc',
  component: Abc,
  name: 'abc'},
{
  path: '/abc/:xyz',
  component: Abc,
  name: 'abcXyz'
}])
```

and then use the one that you need

> ```
> <a [routerLink]="['/abcXyz',{xyz: blabla}]">
>      and 
> <a [routerLink]="['/abc']">
> ```

If `routeCongig` is located in your root file, use `/` before root's name and if it's on the second level or something, use

```
<a [routerLink]="['/parentRoot', {parentParams:value}, '/abc']">
```

Comment: already tried this not working

Comment: by the way as of now `as` has been changed with `name`

Comment: thanks for reminding , updated !!

Comment: But why ? what's the error ?

Comment: error as explained in question. on refresh does't show anything on window

Comment: Got working now, found my error, thanks.

Comment: nice! glad to hear that.

Comment: The only problem with this is that /abc will reload page when moving to /abc/xyz

Answer (score 0):

You can put both together,

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/abc/:xyz', component: Abc,  name: 'abc' }
    { path: '/abc', component: Abc, name: 'abc' },
])
```

if this doesn't work as expected, you should see below,

`Optional routeparams #3525`
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3525

Comment: already tried this not working

Comment: by the way as of now `as` has been changed with `name`

Comment: I think now you should look into the issue given to you.

Comment: yeah again already saw this issue :p for previous comment see this update http://stackoverflow.com/a/33196880/5043867

Comment: Yes my mistake changing `as` to `name`.

Comment: <a [routerLink]="['product-list']" [queryParams]="{ page: 99 }">Go to Page 99</a>