# Default parameters for Components on Angular2's router-deprecated

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm building a custom CMS with Angular2 and I have two types of posts (let's call them `typeA` and `typeB`) that are identical except for this type property.

I'd like to reuse my `PostListComponent` and `PostEditorComponent` for both types but those having a different URL.

I was thinking on adding to my `RouteDefinition[]` (I'm still using `2.0.0-rc.2` with `@angular/router-deprecated`):

```
{
    path      : '/admin/type-a',
    name      : 'Type A Post List',
    component : PostListComponent,
    arguments : { 'type' : 'typeA' }
}, {
    path      : '/admin/type-b',
    name      : 'Type B Post List',
    component : PostListComponent,
    arguments : { 'type' : 'typeB' }
}
```

But I can't find any documentation on how to pass this default argument to a Component. On SO I've just found [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36986291/1534704), but it's not the same issue and I wouldn't like to be using a workaround like that.

Any hint will be much appreciated!

Comment: Finding documentation on an obsolete, RC version is of course harder than finding it on the final, current version. The new, final router allows specifying data on a route. My hint is: migrate to the final version. The sooner you do it, the less work it will require.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet. Do you know any good resources/guides for upgrading from `2.0.0-rc.2` to the current release (`2.1.1` or `2.1.2`)?

Comment: The most important change is the module system. I would read the section of the official angular doc, that describes them.

Comment: I've also used this [guide](https://www.barbarianmeetscoding.com/blog/2016/08/13/updating-your-angular-2-app-from-rc4-to-rc5-a-practical-guide/).