# Routing angular2: Nothing appears

Tags: routes, angular

I'm trying to implement basic routing with Angular2 but without success :-D Actually, I don't even have an error, I just get nothing on the page (which does not help me to debug the issue ^^). Here's what I did:

- Bootstrap "*ROUTER_PROVIDERS*" from '*angular/router*'
- Define the routes in the main component (see below).
- Add a "*router-outlet*" element in the template of the main component.
- The main component implements "*ngOnInit*" and uses the router to redirect the user to the route named "*Company*".

The routes:

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/company', component: CompanyComponent, name: 'Company' },
    { path: '/missions', component: MissionComponent, name: 'Mission' }
])
```

When I access my page, I'm correctly redirected to "*/company*", so it looks like the routes are correctly defined, but still, I don't see anything. I tried to add the "*company*" element in the main component template to see if this component was OK, and when I do that, it appears correctly, so I don't think that's a component related issue.

I checked the live example from angular tutorial and the only difference I see is that they use "*Routes*" decorator instead of "*RouteConfig*". When I do that, WebStorm only found "*Routes*" in "*angular2/alt_router*" and it does not work anyway (I have an error saying Angular does not find my routes)...

It just looks like if the "*router-outlet*" is not found/filled up, but I have no idea why.

I'm using angular2 beta 17

Comment: kind of difficult to say anything without AppComponent, CompanyComponent and MissionComponent code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference you have between the documentation you are reading and the code you are using is the angular version. If you go to the site of [Angular2 Routing & Navigation link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) you can see in bold it states:

```
This chapter is a work in progress.

It describes the release candidate Component Router which replaces the beta router.
```

The version you are using is the old one, for which the documentation can be found [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router-deprecated.html)

There you can check the sample app to see what's different from your implementation.

However I would suggest you upgrade to the RC version of angular2 instead of using the beta version.

Comment: Just did that, now... nothing works anymore ^^ But I just took a look at the quick start en it looks like a lot of thing has changed in the systemjs configuration and right now, my app can't seem to load "core.js", "router.js",... So I guess I have to update my configuration. I'll come back here when I can get something to work. Thanks

Comment: Ah aaaah. That was it. After switching to rc1, I finally got it to work. Thanks ;-)

Comment: You are welcome. I'm learning and trying to work with Angular 2 since alpha :) Lot was constantly changing, but at least know that we are getting to the final release things are settling down :)