# How to use child routes in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-routing

**Angular 2 version: 2.0.0-alpha.44**

I've been trying to do routing in Angular 2. Though i was able to do the normal routing done, i am facing some issues when i introduce child routes. Here is the example on plnkr  (http://plnkr.co/edit/Y5doqU1WcEe4Ldr7KfPJ)

Below is the code for quick reference. I am trying to achieve below routing

```
                                  App
                                  /\
                                 /  \
                             HomeCmp HelloCmp
                                      \
                                       \
                                     ChildCmp
```

And below is how i've configured my paths

```
import {bootstrap, bind, Component, View} from 'angular2/angular2'
import {RouteConfig, RouteParams, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, APP_BASE_HREF, ROUTER_BINDINGS} from 'angular2/router'

@Component({
  selector: 'child-cmp'
})
@View({
  template: `
    <div>
      <h3>Whats up</h3>
    </div>
  `
})
class ChildCmp { }

// ************************ Hello Component ***********************************
@Component({
  selector: 'hello-cmp'
})
@View({
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello there !</h2>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: ROUTER_DIRECTIVES
})
@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/', component: ChildCmp, as: 'ChildCmp'}
])
class HelloCmp { }

//************************** HOME Component ***********************************
@Component({
  selector: 'home-cmp'
})
@View({
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Welcome Home</h2>
    </div>
  `
})
class HomeCmp {}

//************************* APP Component *************************************
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cmp'
})
@View({
  template: `
    <div>
      <h1>Hello {{message}}!</h1>
      <a [router-link]="['./HomeCmp']">home</a>
      <a [router-link]="['./HelloCmp']">hello</a>
      <hr>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: ROUTER_DIRECTIVES
})
@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/', component: HomeCmp, as: 'HomeCmp'}
  {path: '/hello/...', component: HelloCmp, as: 'HelloCmp'}
])
export class App {
  message:string = 'world';
}

bootstrap(App, [
  ROUTER_BINDINGS,
  bind(APP_BASE_HREF).toValue(location.pathname)
]);
```

When i remove child routes it works fine. But with child routes i get below error.

```
EXCEPTION: Link "["HelloCmp"]" does not resolve to a terminal or async instruction. in [null]
```

I followed the article mentioned [here](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/routing-in-angular-2.0). **But not able to get it working. Can someone please help ?** Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need to import the child component in the `routerLink` then your code is working fine. For example:

```
<a [routerLink]="['./HelloCmp','ChildCmp']">hello</a>
```

Here is the working plnkur of your code.
<kbd>[Plunker Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/ABMjGbJbbURBD9KioV7v?p=preview)</kbd>

For more info about this routing see this issue on github [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5123)

## Update to Angular 2 beta

As of Angular 2 beta some changes are here:

- `router-link` has been changed to routerLink
- You can also use `useAsDefault : true` instead of providing child at the time of routerLink like this -

  {path: '/blabla', components: ABC , name : ABC, useAsDefault: true}

Comment: @Pradeep Jain Thanks a lot. What if i want to invoke the route from the code and not using [router-link] ? Like for ex in above example, using router.navigate(['./HelloCmp']).

Comment: @Pradeep Got it. We need to use router.navigate(['./HelloCmp', 'ChildCmp'). It became clear after reading the link suggested by you. Also i found one more good link (https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/RouterLink-class.html)

Comment: will you provide plunkr that showing usage of router.navigate as u said u have done with this.

Comment: @Pradeep: Here it is. You can navigate to './HelloCmp' by clicking the button which programitically navigates to HelloCmp . Plnkr link is here [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/6NnuSKTY6QWMVps9UFVA?p=preview)

Comment: Wouldn't be `['HelloCmp','ChildCmp']` be the same as `['./HelloCmp','ChildCmp']`?

Comment: i Don't about `['HelloCmp','ChildCmp']` but yes if we write `['./HelloCmp','ChildCmp']` than angualr router will instead look in the current component's children for the route

Answer (score 5):

**Angular4 child Routing** -

> Let me first define the route configuration, each route can have a
>   property called children where you can define the child routes of this
>   route.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'find', redirectTo: 'search'},
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'search', component: SearchComponent},
  {
  path: 'artist/:artistId',
  component: ArtistComponent,
  children: [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'tracks'}, ①
  {path: 'tracks', component: ArtistTrackListComponent}, ②
  {path: 'albums', component: ArtistAlbumListComponent}, ③
  ]
  },
  {path: '**', component: HomeComponent}
];
```

1. If a user navigates to say /artist/1234 it will redirect to
   /artist/1234/tracks .
2. This route matches a URL like /artist/1234/tracks.
3. This route matches a URL like /artist/1234/albums.

> ```
> <h1>Artist</h1>
> <p>
>   <a [routerLink]="['./tracks']">Tracks</a> |
>   <a [routerLink]="['./albums']">Albums</a>
> </p>
> <router-outlet></router-outlet>
> ```