# Child Routing in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have one parent component

parent.html

```
  @RouteConfig([        
    { path: '/ChildOne', component: ChildOne, name: "ChildOne",useAsDefault: true},
    { path: '/ChildTwo', component: ChildTwo, name: "ChildTwo"}
 ])
```

parent.ts

```
<a [routerLink]="['./ChildOne',{Id:5}]">childOne </a>
<a [routerLink]="['./ChildTwo',{Id:1}]">chilTwo </a>
```

child1 Component

`childOne.ts`

```
constructor(public params: RouteParams)
    { this.childId=params.get("Id"); }
```

childOne.html

```
{{childId}}
```

child2 Component

```
childTwo.ts

constructor(public params: RouteParams)
    { this.childId=params.get("Id"); }

childTwo.html

{{childId}}
```

Now the problem is that the 'Id' of childOne is not getting by default (useAsDefault).

while the 'id' is getting after the click of childOne or childTwo

Answer (score 0):

To indicate a route has child routes add `...` to the path

```
{ path: '/ChildOne/...', component: ChildOne, name: "ChildOne",useAsDefault: true},
{ path: '/ChildTwo/...', component: ChildTwo, name: "ChildTwo"},
```

and add the child component to the router link

```
<a [routerLink]="['./ChildOne', 'ChildOne', {Id:5}]">childOne </a>
<a [routerLink]="['./ChildTwo', 'ChildTwo', {Id:1}]">chilTwo </a>
```

See also [How to use child routes in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33840219/how-to-use-child-routes-in-angular-2)