# Angularjs 2 Routing: redirect to dashboard after login

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular

I'm using Angular2 beta.14.

What I want to do is creating a dummy login and then redirecting user to the protected overview page which has links to other components.

Like this,

1. before login, visit `localhost:3000/` or any protected pages will be redirected to `localhost:3000/dummylogin`
2. after users login, redirect user to `localhost:3000/overview`

Right now, I have

`app.component` - contains route config for `/dummylogin`

`overview.component` - contains route config for `/update` etc.

`dummy-login.component` - contains route config for `/overview`

In the login component, I tried to use `this.router.navigateByUrl(['Overview'])` to redirect user to the `Overview` component after doing dummy authentication. But I got this error

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Child routes are not allowed for "/dummylogin".    
Use "..." on the parent's route path.
```

This error msg doesn't make sense to me. And, I'm not sure if I'm on the right direction. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Child routes are not allowed for "/dummylogin". Use "..." on the parent's route path.

As its clear from the error you have to define child routing in order to  make your app work,
so you have to add `/...` in the add of routing of dummylogin like this

```
@RouteConfig([
{ path: '/dummylogin/...', as: 'DummyLogin', component: DummyLogin}
])
```

so as per angular2's routing rule you have to define one route at the time of child routing or to `useAsDefault: true`

so in the dummylogin you have to define routing and define at lease one default route like this -

```
@RouteConfig([
{ path: '/overview', as: 'overview', component: overview, useAsDefault : true}

....
```

])

see also

- [How to use child routes in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33842769/5043867)

Comment: This solution answers my question though I currently realize that my routing design was bad. Right now, I add route config for `/DummyLogin` and `/RouteDispatcher` in the root app component. And the RouteDispatcher component contains child route config for other components like `/Overview` etc.

Answer (score 0):

So you start with /, then go to /dummylogin and then try to go /dummylogin/overview - child route, perhaps its treated as relative path without slash. I guess you should use `this.router.navigateByUrl(['/Overview'])`.

Comment: may be it is case-sensitive also, check that router config and url match: Overview->overview.

Answer (score 0):

Since dummy login routes are child routes of parent app component, you'll need to specify that in the app's `RouteConfig`. This is done by adding `/...` to the end of that route's path.

Example:

```
@RouteConfig([
   { path: '/dummylogin/...', as: 'DummyLogin', component: DummyLogin }
])
export class AppComponent {
...
}
```

edit:

I don't think you want to have overview as a child route of dummylogin though, so what you'll want is to define both routes in the RouteConfig of the parent app component and access the router in the login component using dependency injection. I've made a [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/YyvEg4LlnL37DSvugyFC?p=preview)

Comment: Well, I tried it which prompts "link does not resolve to a terminal instruction". Then I added `useAsDefault: true` to the route config of `dummy-login.component`. Then, the login page appears but it's url is `http://localhost:3000/dummylogin/overview`

Comment: The way it's been setup with overview as a child route of dummylogin that's how the route will resolve. Chances are you want to have a flat routing system where overview is not a child route of dummylogin. In this case you don't need a RouteConfig decorator on the DummyLogin component. I've updated the original answer with the link.