# Runtime preview of selected html template

Tags: angularjs, html, typescript, angular

I am new in angular2.I am working with angular 2 and facing issue as follows

1]I have been designed 2-3 template like email template,sms template which will take predefined data and display that data

2]I have been designed screen which contains dropdown with name like email,sms etc
email option has link to email template and same for sms.

The main thing is i want to show the selected template view as a preview of that template.Means if i select sms then the sms template will be shown in given section of the same page.(like upload image preview.)

is it possible?

Thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

Yes obviously, you have to use `Routuing` for the same, by using routing in angular2 you will be able to 
navigate throughout the pages and you can show whatever page you want to display

see also :-

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

latest Updated to angular2 RC1 (wroth reading)

- https://coryrylan.com/blog/introduction-to-angular-2-routing
- [Angular 2 router examples + @Routes typing support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36823186/5043867)
- [How to use child routes in Angular 2.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33842769/5043867)